# Какую перспективную альтернативу вы знаете для C?

Tags: c++, c, разработка-игр

С - великолепный язык с широкими возможностями, несмотря на свой преклонный возраст. В качестве перспективных альтернатив ему появились многие интересные и производительные и удобные (относительно) языки - D, Rust, Go. Для глядя на современный GameDev, то для ААА-games в первую очередь используется едва ли не монопольно - C++, но при его возможностях приводит в ужас большинство.

Какие производительные альтернативы C (за исключением C++) вы используете для игровых проектов?

Comment: А есть какие-то достаточно производительные альтернативы кроме плюсов?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в этом, можно сказать, и состоит вопрос.

Comment: Вы ведь уже поискали сравнительные тесты производительности, да?

Comment: Например, Unity? Графический движок можно писать хоть на ассемблере, а для игровой логики нужен высокоуровневый язык.

Comment: Трансляторы в С++, например, haxe+hxcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я пишу на Си, но не игровые проекты.

Как известно, Си это *простой* язык, можно сказать -- макроассемблер с типами.
Собственно, он лежит в основе (внутри) кучи средств программирования высокого уровня, все эти Python, Lisp, PHP ..., кучи СУБД и т.д. и т.п. в значительной степени реализованы на нем.

И если его  минимализм и близость к конкретной ОС и железу нравится, то вряд ли надо его всерьез расширять (за исключением использования уже существующих в gcc расширений).

Думаю, что реально нужны не альтернативы, а разработка и широкое использование (некая стандартизация, если угодно) удобного аналога [C++ STL контейнеры](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) и [algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/).